# "Соскучась". Можно ли так говорить и писать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастия

Можно ли говорить и писать **"соскучась"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можно ли сказать "соскучась"?

**МОЖНО.** Правильно и "соску'чившись", и "соску́чась".

См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/69302/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F :

[image]

*(Источник: «Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку»)*

====

**Примеры** с "соскучась" см. в Нацкорпусе: http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EE%F1%EA%F3%F7%E0%F1%FC&p=0 :

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, slava!

Answer (score 2):

Не буду говорить, что я являюсь истинной в последней инстанции, но мне кажется, что правильным вариантом в любом контексте будет: "Соскучившись".

Answer (score 1):

Сказать-то можно что угодно. А как быть с правилом для 6 класса: дееприч. несов.в. имеют суффиксы -а,-я; а совершенного -в, вши, -ши? От глагола сов.вида образуются дееприч. сов. вида. Следовательно, соскучившись.

Comment: А попробуйте-ка образовать деепричастие от глагола сов. вида "прийти".

Я бы сказал: придя.

А Вы?

Comment: Я бы помолчала, а потом пришла к выводу: русский язык богат и могуч. Как с теорией-то быть?

Comment: А теория говорит о том, что суффиксы деепричастий НЕ ЯВЛЯЮТСЯ средством выражения их видовых значений; можно говорить лишь о ТИПИЧНОСТИ или НЕТИПИЧНОСТИ того или иного суффикса для деепричастий того или иного вида.===
Прочесть, зачесть... Принести, разгрести... ???

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.